# Generating classes for rows using SQLFORM.factory

Tags: web2py

I'd like to generate a form from multiple tables using SQLFORM.factory, and I'd like the rows in 
the form to be labeled with classes corresponding to the tables from which they were generated. For example:

```
SQLFORM.factory(db.table1, db.table2)
```

and the accompanying code to generate classes, should generate something like this:

```
...
<tbody>
    <tr id = 'no_table_field1__row' class = 'table1_field'></tr>
    <tr id = 'no_table_field2__row' class = 'table1_field'></tr>
    <tr id = 'no_table_field1__row' class = 'table2_field'></tr>
    <tr id = 'no_table_field2__row' class = 'table2_field'></tr>
</tbody>
...
```

By default, it seems that the ids generated by SQLFORM.factory start with "no_table_".

Is there a quick and easy way to generate classes, or at least to have the auto-generated names of the ids correspond to the table names? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really an easy way to do what you want with `SQLFORM.factory`. You can change "no_table" to something else via the `table_name` argument, but that will affect all the form input fields. If you want to use `SQLFORM.factory` (as opposed to generating a custom form), then you'll have to use the [server-side DOM](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05/the-views#Server-side-DOM-and-parsing) to manipulate the form object after it has been created. Something like:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(db.table1, db.table2)
for f in [f for f in db.table1] + [f for f in db.table2]:
    if f.type != 'id' and f.readable and f.writable:
        form.element('tr[id=no_table_%s__row]' % f.name).add_class(
            '%s_%s' % (f.tablename, f.name))
```

The above iterates through all the `Field` objects in the two tables, and for each one, it finds the associated `TR` element in the form based on the `id` and then adds a class to the `TR`.